# averaging half-hourly data for weekdays only

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to obtain the average (over 24 hours at 30 minute intervals) of a section of time-series data.

Currently I have:

```
# Data of interest
START = datetime(2010,2,1,0,0,0)
END = datetime(2010,2,8,23,59,59)

# Function to group by time of day
def minutes(date):
    time = date.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    dt = datetime.strptime("2009-04-01 " + time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return dt

# Truncate data to desired section
telford = store.get_data("spd_mw").TELR.truncate(START,END)

# Group and average
telford.groupby(minutes).mean()
```

I've tried using `asfreq(datetools.BDay())` but it removes the half-hourly data. Is it a case of writing my own DateOffset?

Is there a cleaner way to group the above data by minutes?

On an aside: does truncate need to be existing indexes in the data? I'm getting the following error (on a different set of data to above):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "power-weather.py", line 21, in <module>
    egph_temp = store.get_data("weather_EGPH").TemperatureC.truncate(START,END)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/generic.py", line 702, in truncate
    result = self.ix[before:after]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 35, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 167, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 372, in _get_slice_axis
    i, j = labels.slice_locs(start, stop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 842, in slice_locs
    beg_slice = self.get_loc(start)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pandas-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/index.py", line 523, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "engines.pyx", line 101, in pandas._engines.DictIndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/engines.c:2498)
  File "engines.pyx", line 108, in pandas._engines.DictIndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/src/engines.c:2460)
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: As a first sentence, it would have been nice if you told us what you were trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
def weekdays(date):
    if 0 < int(datetime.strftime(date, "%w")) < 6:
        return True
    return False

def weekends(date):
    if int(datetime.strftime(date, "%w")) == (0 or 6):
        return True
    return False

telford = telford.select(weekdays)
```